# Funny names of mathematical objects?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

What are funny names of mathematical objects?

For example [Mouse (set theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_(Set_Theory))

Comment: you can find many at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1102872/87355

Comment: Perverse sheaves, of course.

Comment: Dessins d'Enfants. They don't look like children drawings but they might look like what a mathematician thinks what the drawings of children look like!

Comment: I always found it funny that some of the most studied objects in modern mathematics are the "simple complex Lie groups"

Comment: I voted to close for the following reasons. (a) First of all there seems to be the exact same question on MSE. (b) I also observe that the answers below are just lists of expressions; people don't quite take the time to explain what it is about, what is funny about it, or just even provide a url; these answers are not very informative.

Comment: How can a question with 2 downvotes (ATM) have only answers with $\geq 2$ upvotes?

Comment: What’s funny is entirely in the eyes of the beholder.

Comment: @user347489 if you click on the "-2" you'll see it's actually 11 upvotes and 13 downvotes.

Comment: Do you know what conductor (number theory) is called in German?

Answer (score 6):

1. "Normal family".
2. "Shared values" (a popular research area in the theory of meromorphic functions. Many theorems in this area say that "a family (of functions) is normal if its
   members share enough values").
3. "G-oper" (this  was introduced by a Russian speaker, and both "oper" and
   "G-oper" sound very funny to a Russian speaker).

Comment: left / right ideals

Comment: Could you elaborate on what makes them funny for a Russian speaker?

Comment: @Federico Poloni: "oper" is a slang word for "cop". "G-oper" as it is pronounced in Russian  is associated with "жопа", which means "ass", "arse". So if you want to call a cop "asshole", you can use this word and everyone would understand what you mean.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: Additionally, from my limited understanding as a non-native English speaker, goper means a Republican (GOPer), but also has a certain slang meaning according to urban dictionary.

Comment: @M. G. Looking in a slang dictionary I found only "gopher", which is pronounced differently.

Comment: @M.G. Thanks. You may remove it now if you find in inappropriate. When V. Drinfeld introced this term he did not know American slang; he was working in Kharkiv at that time, and had never traveled abroad before.

Comment: @M. G. The "g" in "goper" (slang) is probably pronounced in English like the first letter in "golf", while in the matematical term G-oper it is pronounced as "G" in "George"  which is consistent with Russian pronounciation:-)

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: I removed the link and thanks for that bit of mathematical language trivia :) Yes, I believe you are correct that goper is pronounced as гопер/гоупър rather than жопа.

Answer (score 6):

"Pure motives" [and thus also "mixed motives", as **Will Sawin** comments]

(there's also "Killing fields", but if that's funny then it's gallows humor)

Comment: Surely "Mixed motives" too.

Comment: I *thought* I was missing something!  Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

[Sexy Primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexy_prime)!

(and this is to reach 30 characters)

Comment: Hello @hbjj, welcome on MO :-). In general it is better to avoid very short answers that are not very informative. You could explain in your answer what these numbers are. The least to do (which I did by editing your answer) is to provide a link to a webpage where an explanation/definition is given.

Answer (score 5):

1. Perverse sheaves: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perverse_sheaf
2. Blowing up points on a plane: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_up
3. Balls?... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(mathematics)#In_topological_spaces
4. Hairy ball theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem
5. Tropical geometry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_geometry
6. Radicals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_ideal
7. Cardinals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number
8. Sheets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Formal_definition or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface
9. Twin primes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime
10. Necklace splitting theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_splitting_problem

Comment: 9a. Sexy primes <en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexy_prime> 
[now I see **hbjj** mentioned this 20 minutes ago]

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: sadly, the choice of terminology excludes the somewhat kinky possibility of sexy twin primes.

Answer (score 5):

["Derogatory matrix"](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Non-derogatory_matrix) ... the minimal polynomial is a proper divisor of the characteristic polynomial